# Liquidsoap + JACK latency

Tags: audio, latency, low-latency, jack, liquidsoap

**How to minimize Liquidsoap's processing latency?**

I have written a very simple liquidsoap script to test latency:

```
#!/usr/bin/env liquidsoap

set("log.stdout",true)
set("log.file",false)

stream = input.jack(clock_safe=false)
output.jack(stream)
```

When I connect the ports with music player (mpd) and soundcard, music playback starts and stops with about 0.5s latency. I have JACK buffer size set to 1024 so the latency should be about 0.02s. When I connect mpd directly to soundcard, the latency is unnoticable so it's definitely problem with Liquidsoap.

Is there any configuration option I'm missing which causes unwanted buffering when set to default value? I tried various clock_safe values for input and output but they do nothing.

Comment: As far as I know, you won't be able to lower any of the internal buffers.  If you need a tool built with low latencies in mind, I don't think Liquidsoap is what you're looking for.

Comment: Found this thread from the mailing list as well:
http://sourceforge.net/p/savonet/mailman/message/31767440/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/reference.html), `input.jack` takes a buffer_size parameter:

```
buffer_size (int – defaults to 2): Set buffer size, in frames. Must be >= 1.
```

Looks like its set to `2` by default, so not sure if you are going to gain much by setting it to 1...